# How do I merge 2 tables such that the result is flattened/merged?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following 2 Tables

**Table1:**

```
TID         |Traning
---------------------------
1           |Training 1
2           |Training 2
3           |Training 3
```

**Table2:**

```
ID      |TID        |Status
-----------------------------------
1234567 |1          |1
1234567 |2          |1
1234567 |3          |1
```

I want to construct a new view such that the result looks like the following,

**Result:**

```
ID      |[Training 1 Status] |[Training 2 Status] |[Training 3 Status]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234567 |1                   |1                   |1
```

How do I achieve this in SQL Server?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the `PIVOT` command...  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
    (
      ID VARCHAR(10) ,
      TID INT ,
      Status INT
    )
CREATE TABLE #table2 ( TID INT, Training varchar(10) )

--DROP TABLE #table1,#table2


INSERT INTO #table1
        ( ID, TID, Status )
SELECT  '1234567' AS [ID] ,
        '1' AS [TID] ,
        '1' AS [Status]
UNION ALL
SELECT  '1234567' AS [ID] ,
        '2' AS [TID] ,
        '1' AS [Status]
UNION ALL
SELECT  '1234567' AS [ID] ,
        '3' AS [TID] ,
        '1' AS [Status] 

INSERT  INTO #table2
        ( TID ,
          [Training]
        )
        SELECT  '1' AS [TID] ,
                'Training 1' AS [Training]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  '2' AS [TID] ,
                'Training 2' AS [Training]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  '3' AS [TID] ,
                'Training 3' AS [Training] 


SELECT  *
FROM    #table1


SELECT  *
FROM    #table2;



WITH temp_CTE  AS (SELECT  a.ID,b.TID,a.[Status] AS [Training Status]
FROM    #table1 a INNER JOIN #table2 b ON a.TID=b.TID)



SELECT  ID ,
        [1] AS [Training1] ,
        [2] AS [Training2] ,
        [3] AS [Training3]
FROM    ( SELECT    ID ,
                    TID ,
                    [Training Status]
          FROM       temp_CTE
        ) p PIVOT
( MAX([Training Status]) FOR tid IN ( [1], [2], [3] ) ) AS pvt
```

What you really need in the above code is the pivot and the join commands the previous code is just me creating the table so I can experiment with the data.

Comment: Awesome thanks, is it possible to take the column names dynamically? such that I do not mention,
`'Training 1' AS [Training]` etc ?

Comment: Why do we need Inner Join when we are doing `[1] AS [Training1]` for example? I could achieve it without inner join, have a look here, 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/595d2/5 .
Am I missing something?

Comment: I just used the inner join inside the CTE to combine your two tables the type of join just depepnds on your requirements. and yes you can create a dynamic sql which chooses the training columns depending on the the training column in #table2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   SELECT ID,[1] AS [Training 1 Status] , [2] AS [Training 2 Status],[3] AS [Training 3 Status] FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT Table_2.[ID],Table_2.TID,Table_2.[Status] FROM Table_1 INNER JOIN 
Table_2 ON Table_1.TID=Table_2.TID)  [Source_Tab] PIVOT 
(MAX([Status]) FOR [TID] IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS [Pivot_Tab];
```